# A couple of questions on mass increase

Tags: special-relativity, mass, mass-energy

I found these [experimental data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_relativistic_energy_and_momentum#Bertozzi_experiment) on mass increase.

[image]

> Data of the Bertozzi experiment show close agreement with special
>   relativity. Kinetic energy of five electron runs: 0.5, 1, 1.5, 4.5, 15
>   MeV (or 1, 2, 3, 9, 30 in mc²). Speed: 0.752, 0.828, 0.922, 0.974, 1.0
>   in c (or 0.867, 0.910, 0.960, 0.987, 1 in c²).

- Do you know of any link where I can find more precise experimental data (say accurate to five digits) for [relativistic mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity) increase? 
  For example, in the above table, is 0.5 MeV a rounded figure for 0.511? supposing the latter, what is the exact mass increase, exacly one mass + the usual rest mass, so the total mass is 2.00000 $m_e$? speed is rather accurate: 0.752 c.
- At what speed/energy there is minimum agreement with the SR formula? according to the picture it is about 5-6 MeV, is this correct?
- Can you also specify if "increased mass" means that the body exerts an increased (and exactly proportional) gravitational force? Does it mean that an electron with 1 GeV Ke exerts a pull equal to a proton?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ives%E2%80%93Stilwell_experiment#Modern_experiments. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_relativistic_energy_and_momentum. There is no such thing as "relativistic mass" in modern physics. That was a poor way of treating relativity and we have given up on that quite a while ago.

Comment: @CuriousOne, you are suggesting to me the very article I cited in my post

Comment: Did you read it? It seems to contain the references for more precise experiments. Am I missing something?

Comment: You aren't going to find recent data because no-one would be interested in doing the experiment. Special relativity is so well tested that it's a boring experiment to do. NB the energy is related to the momentum not the mass. Use $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$ where $m$ is the rest mass and $p$ is the relativistic momentum given by $p=\gamma mv$.

Comment: Well there are still experiments on aspects of special relativity: only because something is thought to be well understood and well tested does not mean that experiments with even higher precission and new methods are "boring". I do not know a recent experiment on the energy momentum relation of SRT but I know of a recent experiment on time dialation: http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.120405 .

Comment: @M.J.Steil, thanks,could you briefly explain what the experiment proves? If it is important, can you woirk it up into an answer?my question wanted to probe if the formula is accurate enough